# In Django filtering on __isnull seems to result in LIKE 'None'

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with the following field

```
class Callstat(models.Model):
agentdisplayname = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=60, db_column='AgentDisplayName', blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = u'callstat'

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%d: %s' % (self.callid, self.telnum)
```

However when I do the following,

```
call = Callstat.objects.all().filter(agentdisplayname__isnull=True)
```

MySQL's general_log shows the resulting SQL as

```
SELECT `callstat`.`AgentDisplayName` FROM `callstat` WHERE `callstat`.`AgentDisplayName` LIKE 'None';
```

The data in the database is added by a separate application and I have no control over the fact that it is leaving fields as NULL. I'm fairly certain this **can't** be a bug in Django so any help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: OK turns out I'd missed something further down in my code, and this filter had been overwritten by a __exact filter in a loop.

Comment: Granted, I'm using PostgreSQL, not MySQL, but in Django 1.3.1, it's using IS NULL in the SQL, not LIKE 'None'. MySQL does support IS NULL, though, so I see no reason why Django would do something different there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `null=True` on your column. By default [null parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) it is set to false, which means `NULL` is not a permitted value.

```
agentdisplayname = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=60, db_column='AgentDisplayName', blank=True, null=True)
```

Probably you would need to change the existing db column as well.

Comment: As you can see from the question and from your quoting of it, null=True is already set (as the first attribute)

Comment: Yes, as there are NULLs in the database and the database was created form the Django model

Comment: What versions of Django and MySQL driver are you using? I reproduced your case and it seems to be using IS NULL on my setup.

Comment: Django: 1.3.1
Python-MySQLdb: 1.2.3

Comment: Oh and MySQL 5.1.52 (if that makes any difference)